# PHP : Simple DOM Parser how to iterate this html code

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<div id="score">
               <div class="name"><span style="width:68%">A</span></div>
                   <span class="roll">1</span>    

                <div class="name"><span style="width:60%">B</span></div>
                   <span class="roll">2</span>       

                 <div class="name"><span style="width:56%">C</span></div>
                   <span class="roll">3</span>          
 </div>
```

i want to iterate over each span of **div.name** but i am not getting to next **span.roll** tag I have used this code yet and also check the condition  if A is available then 1 display and same as above name to check.

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");
$obj = new simple_html_dom();

 foreach ($obj->find('div[id=score]') as $factor)
    {
         $item = $factor->find('div[class=name] span')->plaintext;

          if(trim($item) == 'A')
          { 
             $a = $factor->find('span[class=roll]',0)->plaintext;
          }
          if(trim($item) == 'B')
          { 
            $b = $factor->find('span[class=roll]',1)->plaintext;
          }
          if(trim($item) == 'C')
          { 
             $c = $factor->find('span[class=roll]',2)->plaintext;
          }
           $final_array['overalldata'] = array
           (
            'a'=> $a,
            'b' => $b,
            'c' => $c,

            );
    }
   print_r($final_array);
   die;


?>
```

Any body having any idea please help to sort it out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an alternative, since you're targeting that ID, you don't need to have a `foreach` on the parent element, just get it outright.

Then you apply the `foreach` on its children, getting the *names* and *rolls*.

Here's the idea:

```
$final_array['overalldata'] = null; // initialize
$factor = $obj->find('div[id=score]', 0); // get the parent
foreach ($factor->find('div[class=name]') as $item) { // each item of the parent
    $name = $item->find('span', 0)->innertext; // get the name
    $roll = $item->next_sibling()->innertext; // get the next sibling which is the roll
    $final_array['overalldata'][$name] = $roll; // and assign it (push it inside the array)

}
print_r($final_array);
```

So basically, to get the `name` just target the child inside each `div`, and then, to target the `roll` (which is the sibling of each `div`), just use `->next_sibling()` method.

Sidenote: If I were you, I'd stick to [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php). It's already built-in inside PHP, no need to include any third party libraries.